# Python Linter disable warnings isn't working for VSCode

Tags: python, pylint

I currently have the following in my `settings.json` file:

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
...
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=line-too-long",
    "--disable=unused-argument"
]
```

I have other arguments, but for the sake of clarity I only included these. The problem is that despite adding the arguments (I've also tried adding their codes found from [here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html)) the messages still persist.

Does anyone know anything I can try to disable the messages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error I couldn't solve myself. But recently I saw a new extension being added to VS Code.

[`PyLance`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/)

Now this is a new language support for python. You can install it and use it in order to replace `PyLint`

I am sure this will help.

Thank You! :D

Comment: I actually have PyLance installed and enabled lol. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Seankala NeverMind!

Comment: Not really an answer to the original issue, just proposing a workaround.